# How to query the reference type data stored in object type in FireStore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

If you can check in the below image, I'm able to query the data reference in testRef node. But If I'm able to query the data in coRef node like

documentSnapShot.getDocumentReference("coRef/DxFXp3TGc8X8UciPSeqO")

I'm getting exception:

Invalid field path (coRef/DxFXp3TGc8X8UciPSeqO). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'

Not Working Code:

```
 documentSnapshot.getDocumentReference("coRef/"+entry.getKey()).get()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot1 = task.getResult();
                                Log.v("Rajesh","Result"+documentSnapshot1.getData());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Working Code:

```
documentSnapshot.getDocumentReference("testRef")
                            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot1 = task.getResult();
                                Log.v("Rajesh","Result"+documentSnapshot1.getData());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I want to know why I got down vote for my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong:

> Invalid field path (coRef/DxFXp3TGc8X8UciPSeqO). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'

Your path contains a `/` character, as you can see from your line of code:

```
documentSnapShot.getDocumentReference("coRef/DxFXp3TGc8X8UciPSeqO")
```

(It has a an invalid `/` in it.)

If you want to reference properties of objects in a document, try something like this instead:

```
documentSnapShot.getDocumentReference("coRef.DxFXp3TGc8X8UciPSeqO")
```

or maybe

```
documentSnapShot.get(FieldPath.of("coRef", "DxFXp3TGc8X8UciPSeqO"))
```